# Firebase. Auth Failed Network Time out on Sign in

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I have an ionic 1 application and I am getting a weird error on log in only on android.
Only the first time when the user opens the application and logs in, It is logging perfectly. When he logs out and tries to log in again I am getting this error " Auth/Network-Request Failed" and he cannot login unless he closes the application and reopens. I do not get whats the issue and why the first time it is working. This is my code.

```
    <button class="button button-balanced small_button" ng-click="LogIn(user)">
                Sign in
    </button>

    //JS FILE
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword($scope.registerusername, $scope.registerpassword)
    .then(function (user){
        //GO HOMEPAGE
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        alert(errorCode);                 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1. Give us details about your error. Not only `Auth/Network-Request Failed`. Paste here the full error object.
2. Try to upgrade your firebase dependency.

Comment: This is the error message. " network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred". The thing is why after I log out it is happening this. Also what do you mean upgrade your firebase dependency? You mean the version?

Comment: Yes, the version. Try to use the last version. And that error is you paste is not the original error. to this: instead of doing `alert(errorCode)`, try to parse that errorCode object to a full string (like JSON.stringity) and paste here the FULL error. I want to see the full full error object. Something like this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Error. You should have a error id, error message, and more information